# Every comment on the blog is from the 29th of June, this year

Tags: bug, status-completed, blog

All imported comments* on the newly designed blog date from June 29, 2015. Furthermore, they are out of order. In this [Winterbash post](http://blog.stackexchange.com/2015/01/so-long-winter-bash-2014/), it is clear to see that earlier comments are replying to later ones. Maybe some people find reverse chronological order easy to read, though I doubt it, but presenting comments in reverse order with *no indication of that because they all show the same timestamp* is just horribly confusing.

---

* It looks like [all existing comments were imported into the new blog as part of the static content](http://blog.stackexchange.com/2015/07/how-we-built-our-blog/). All comments henceforth use Disqus.

Comment: Example: https://blog.stackexchange.com/2009/06/attribution-required/

Comment: And the post date is weird too. Maybe some date conversion gone wrong. (Not 2015, but 2009, same date however)

Comment: Well, it was all migrated to the new system. The bug is simple, they show date of migration i.e. creation of the record, instead of original posting. :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just submitted a [pull request](https://github.com/StackExchange/blog/pull/90) for this, the USAsians are out today for Independence Day, but I'm sure Jon will merge and re-import as soon as he gets time next week!

Thanks for the report :)

**UPDATE:** That's pushed to production, all the comments use the date of posting rather than the date we generated them.